# What does 'go down with' mean?

Tags: vocabulary, idioms

What does 'go down with' mean here?

http://www.rd.com/true-stories/love/widow-rafting-husbands-ashes/

> What was I doing down there? My sister Kathryn, who had seen me
>   through his death, loves the Grand Canyon, and she arranged the trip.
>
> She said, “Come on, Neshama. It’s the trip of a lifetime. You weren’t
>   able to ***go down with*** John, because it was too far from medical help
>   [for him]. So come.”
>   -- from www.rd.com

Comment: You're generally encouraged to [wait longer](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/1307/not-so-fast-when-should-i-accept-my-answer) before accepting an answer. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this instance, we don't consider "go down" together, but *separately*.

> [down](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/down)
>   2. b :  to or toward a point away from the speaker or the speaker's point of reference

In this example,

> You weren’t able to go ***to [the Grand Canyon]*** with John

Comment: Another example: "I am going down to the store". It is not downhill, just away from where I am now.